# i have a problem when i remove 3 from new arry( ) there is no changing this thing disturb me what is this

Tags: arrays, new-operator

1. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYxhM.png)

```
*
type here
*
xmkosjpscndowdv dwnmo
```

i am try to learn but i have no idea about because i disturb my mind
tell me about it
any one have idea about it can any person know about

i am try to learn but i have no idea about because i disturb my mind
tell me about it
any one have idea about it can any person know about

Comment: That `3` inside `new Array` is creating array of 3 elements. If you remove that, most likely your array becomes 0 length, not accepting any more items.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the "3" from the constructor of the array, the machine will not know how much memory to allocate. So how can you loop through 3 items in the array if the memory was never allocated? You cannot.That would be a memory overflow. You need to allocate the space in the array (3) before you loop that many times through it.